# Uitextfield and UIImageView are overlapping when orientation change

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, autoresizingmask

I want to display a  warning bubble when user enters an invalid email. I can successfully show the bubble but while bubble is present if orientation changes bubble overlaps with uitextfield

View start as Landscape:
[image]

Orientation becomes Portrait:

[image]

Other way around:

View start as Portrait:

[image]

Orientation becomes Landscape (bubble goes further away)

[image]

**My CODE:**

```
//image for warnings
        //get screen size
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        float bubleOriginx;

        //detect device orientation
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation== UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            bubleOriginx=screenRect.size.width*0.95;

        }else
        {
            bubleOriginx=screenRect.size.width*0.72;
        }


        UIImage *bubble = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"create event button.png"]
                       resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 21, 15, 21)];
        self.emailImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bubble];


        self.emailImage.frame = CGRectMake(bubleOriginx, self.email.frame.origin.y+28, 0, 0);
        UILabel  *xlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        xlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
        xlabel.text = string;
        xlabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        CGSize labelSize = [xlabel.text sizeWithFont:xlabel.font
                                   constrainedToSize:xlabel.frame.size
                                       lineBreakMode:xlabel.lineBreakMode];
        xlabel.frame = CGRectMake(
                              xlabel.frame.origin.x, xlabel.frame.origin.y,
                              xlabel.frame.size.width, labelSize.height);


        [xlabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.emailImage addSubview:xlabel];
        self.emailImage.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

        [self.view addSubview:self.emailImage];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.85
                         animations:^(void) {
                             self.emailImage.frame = CGRectMake(bubleOriginx, self.email.frame.origin.y+28, 220, -60);
                             xlabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 210, 60);
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         }];
```

How can I stable that `UIImageview` so it wont overlap? Lets say it will always stay +30 points away from the end point of `uitextfield` or at least wont overlap.

Thanks,
Mord

Comment: Are you using iOS 6? In that case you can use auto layout constraints instead of autoresizing masks, which are much more powerful and allows this kind of constraints.

Comment: No , This is 5.1. App has to be compatible for IOS 5.1 and above.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the autoResizingMask

```
    self.emailImage.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

Keep `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`; (Wont behave the way you expect though)

But setting origin.x on orientation change will solve it.

```
CGRect tempFrame = self.emailImage.frame;
tempFrame.origin.x = textField.frame.origin.x+textField.frame.size.width+30;
self.emailImage.frame = tempFrame;
```

for all orientations. Assuming textField is the reference to the UITextField you have shown in the image.

Comment: what do you mean by `setting origin.x on orientation change will solve it`, So I have to detect orientation change with notification and apply your solution when notification received?

Comment: That would be a way or in the view controller's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, check for the presence of the bubble and write this code there. But before doing all that see if changing the autoResizeMask solves the problem (even though you don't have complete control)

Comment: I have already tried `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin` before posting my question it doesnt work.

Comment: okey. then you could go for the other way in the solution. But if it's okey to have a fixed left margin for the `UITextField`, then setting the same `autoResizingMask` i.e one without `UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleLeftMargin ` to both the text field and the bubble should solve the problem.